# rooting gigaset phone

Tags: rooting, 6.0-marshmallow, root-access

I am trying to root my [Gigaset phone (GS 160)](https://www.gigaset.com/hq_en/cms/service/support-detail/gigaset-gs160.html), but I couldn't make it with

http://kingoapp.com (probably the model is not supported)
and
https://towelroot.com (model is not supported)

Does anyone have another tool in mind that could work?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try [OneRootClick](https://www.oneclickroot.com/)
they have quite a good range of phones they can root.

Comment: Thanks! apparently on https://www.oneclickroot.com/rootable they say they have no support yet  :( ....thanks anyway